# Creating large blob out of small blobs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a large number of tiny blob files created by Azure Application Insights Service.
I would like to combine these blob files and create 1 blob file per hour. This is because we have data on-premises that I would like to integrate this data with and I wouldn't want to download millions of small blob files.

My question is what Azure Service I can use for this?

Comment: There's no single Azure service you need for this (heck - you don't even need to run your code in Azure - you could run it on-premises or anywhere else - not that it would be efficient bandwidth-wise - just making a point). Run your code in whichever service fits your deployment best, whether it's web job, azure function, or something else.

Comment: Can you schedule web jobs to repeatedly run every hour and create 1 file per hour? Is there a better solution than web jobs or azure function? Eventually this stuff will go in HDFS and HDFS does not like large number of small sized files.

Comment: WebJobs and Functions can be easily scheduled to run once per hour. The good thing about WebJobs is that the scheduled one is essentially just a console app.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the Web job is when you have an Azure Web site? If that is the case then we don't have any website in Azure.

Comment: As I know, you could create an empty web app and deploy your WebJob to run your code. You could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to create your WebJob via Azure Portal.